# Columns not aligned in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

As I'm trying to redact my Curiculum, I wrote everything I wanted and then selected all the sections I wanted to have in 2 columns. I applied the layout but I can't get rid of the empty space on top of the second column as seen on the screenshot. Do you have any idea how did this appear ?

I put a column break at the end of the first column and nothing before the title of the 2nd column.

[image]

Comment: Can't really tell you how it became there without playing with the document myself. There is this paragraph button (looks a bit like the pi symbol) that when pressed, it shows all hidden chars, such as enters etc. It should show you what is there.

Comment: Already looked that up, there is nothing [see there](https://i.imgur.com/JxvJQzw.png)

Comment: Added a section break after the blurred part, removed 6 pts spacing before the 2nd column and it fixed everything. Can't really solve the topic since it's tweaking and not a real solution...

Comment: Well, its  solved. You may want to add an answer and accept it, so others know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I just encountered the same problem and think I figured it out.  If the next column begins with a new paragraph, and that paragraph is styled with, say, 12pt spacing before it, the 12pt space will appear.   If you're using something from "Styles" to format the first line of the next column, it's quite possible this is the cause.  Modify the style so the spacing "Before" it is set to 0.  This might mess up the spacing for the rest of your styles and paragraphs, so you may have to remove spacing "Before" and add it "After" all of them.  You can "Modify" a style, click the "Format" menu button in the lower left of the dialog that appears, choose "Paragraph", and then you'll see the choices in the screen shot below.  I hope this helps someone out there.

[Modify Style > Format menu > Paragraph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z52cR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Added a section break after the blurred part, removed 6 pts spacing before the 2nd column and it fixed everything.

Comment: It's more like a workaround. I prefer a solution that doesn't hardcode paragraph formatting just to fix the top alignments.